# How to pass an array as a prop and render in child component in typescript react hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-typescript

I have difficulty passing an array as a prop to a component from the parent and rendering the same in react typescript.

Here is the parent component where the array is been passed.

```
import ReportComponent from '../Components/Reports/ReportComponent';
import { ReportData } from "../Types/ReportData.types";
const Report = () => {
 const [Report, setReport] = useState<ReportData[]>([]);
 ReportService.GetReport()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.data);
        setReport(response.data.data);
        toast.success(response.data.message);
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });

  return <ReportComponent report {...Report}/>;
```

But I discovered that the array is not getting to the child and I am getting is
**TypeError: Report.map is not a function**

```
import { ReportData } from "../../Types/Report.types";
const ReportComponent = (props:ReportData) => {
console.log("props",props)
const [Report, setReport] = useState<ReportData[]>([]);
setReport(props)
return  <div className="row">
         <div className="table-responsive">
      { Report.map((report)=>(  
      <table className="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">UID</th>
            <th scope="col">Value</th>
            <th scope="col">Length</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>    
          <tbody className="table table-striped table-sm">
            <tr>
              <td>{report.name}</td>
              <td>{report.UID}</td>
              <td>{report.Value}</td>
              <td>{report.Length}</td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
       ))}
    </div>
        </div>
}
```

Comment: This code just doesn't make sense in many ways, `setReport(props)` in render function will prob just get you an infinite loop, `<ReportComponent report {...Report}/>` will get you a boolean prop `report` and `Report.length` number of object shape props. Just fix your code.

Comment: And `Report.map` is not a valid code since you dont have `Report` in scope so its actual value is `undefined` (try to log it), you should have a lot of lint warnings and errors at your IDE, notice and fix them.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR:

```
const Report = () => {
    const [report, setReport] = useState<ReportData[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        ReportService.GetReport()
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.data);
                setReport(response.data.data);
                toast.success(response.data.message);
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }, []);

    return <ReportComponent reports={report} />;
);
```

```
interface ReportComponentProps {
    reports: ReportData[];
}

const ReportComponent = ({
    reports,
}: ReportData) => {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="table-responsive">
                {reports.map((report) => (
                    <table className="table table-striped table-sm">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">UID</th>
                                <th scope="col">Value</th>
                                <th scope="col">Length</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody className="table table-striped table-sm">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{report.name}</td>
                                <td>{report.UID}</td>
                                <td>{report.Value}</td>
                                <td>{report.Length}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

1. You should not do things as fetching data (`ReportService.GetReport()...`) inside the render of a component. If you do, every time a component re-renders, that code is executed again, meaning a new fetch will happen.
2. Passing props is done like `<YourComponent propA={propValue} />`
3. Your props do not have the type of `ReportData` (`const ReportComponent = (props:ReportData) => {`. `props` is an *object* with attributes with the names of the actual props.
4. You should not do `setState` inside the render. Just like the fetch, every time the component re-renders, that code is executed again. Because a `setState` causes a re-render, that means that the "render code" is executed again, so another `setState` is executed, that causes another re-render, and so on.
5. If you recive `props` by *properties*, you do not need (and should not) do a `setState(props)`. It is not only redundant, but also causes performance losses.

There are a few other issues with your code. I encourage you to go through the [baiscs of react](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) again.